# Unemployed mother standard visitor visa UK

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

I'm gathering documents for my mother's UK standard visitor visa application. My mother is a housewife. She lives with my father and is fully dependent on my father for day-to-day expenses. My father transfers some amount every month to my mother's account for day-to-day purchases. My mother uses some but saves most of it every month. She has saved around £2000 in her account.

1) what option should I select in the form: Do you have another income or any savings? [image]

2. The transfer is visible in my father's statement as well as my mother's statement. Do I have to document it in the cover letter?.

Answer (score 2):

I would tick both of the boxes in the first option, and submit your father’s bank statements and proof of the source of his income, along with your mother’s statement(s). IIRC, there’s a section at the end of the visa application where you can provide further explanation.